# virtualNetworkRule for Cosmos DB ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-rm-template

I am able to provision a Cosmos DB account using ARM template and i am able to use IP restrictions through template. But when i try to enforce `virtualNetworkRules` through template, by enabling the `isVirtualNetworkFilterEnabled` flag to `true` and giving the ID of already existing vNet, i do not see the change reflected and the vNet is not added.

Can I please know any other way to enforce the flag to `true` and add vNet details to a CosmosDB account (SQL/Mongo as vNet endpoints are available for only those).

```
"isVirtualNetworkFilterEnabled": true,    
"virtualNetworkRules": [
      {
        "id": "/subscriptions/subId/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet1/subnets/subnet1"
      }
    ],
```

Also if the flag is set to false how to pass null in the id.

```
"isVirtualNetworkFilterEnabled": false, 
"virtualNetworkRules": [
      {

      }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding a service endpoint you are essentially enabling "Selected Networks" in the portal.

As noted in [Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/firewall-support?view=azurermps-6.0.0#connections-from-the-azure-portal) section of the doc, the "ipRangeFilter" ip's are set when you enable **Selected Networks**.  I have found that I have to set these in my template for the **Selected Networks** to show up.

```
    "ipRangeFilter": "104.42.195.92,40.76.54.131,52.176.6.30,52.169.50.45,52.187.184.26",
    "isVirtualNetworkFilterEnabled": true,
    "virtualNetworkRules": [
      {
        "id": "[parameters('subnetID')]"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: These 4 IPs enable "Allow access to Azure Portal" option under Selected Networks, which i did add in my template. But the vNet filter property will be set to "False" by default if no vNets are added. So i try to set it to "True" and add subnet ID through template, which is not reflecting once provisioned.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve this by doing below in the ARM template,

```
    "isVirtualNetworkFilterEnabled": true,
    "virtualNetworkRules": [
      {
        "virtualNetworkSubnetId": "[variables('subnetId')]"
      }
    ]
```

And in the variable section, i pass the string like below,

"subnetId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('vnetRG'),'/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('vnetName'), '/subnets/', parameters('vnetSubnetName'))]"

However, when i try to separate this outside of the main template {which creates the cosmosdb account}, we want to use a service account to include the hardening part, which would configure the VNET and set the IPRangeFilter, only the IPRangeFilter works fine, but not the virtualNetworkRules.